# WCF - NetMsmqBinding vs NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

I was going through this article http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx  to choose Binding options.

where i got an unusual doubt of what is mean by

> offline or disconnected interaction, choose the NetMsmqBinding

Does that mean the even if service is not running  still client using the service ?

Can you share some real time example ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 2 bindings are radically different.

- `NetTcpBinding` can be thought of as an MS proprietary format (usually binary) similar in concept to `RPC` (e.g. can be used to replace `.NET Remoting`). It is synchronous, i.e. both client and server must be online at the same time, and the client receives a response (almost) immediately.
- `MSMQ` is a Message Oriented Middleware solution by Microsoft, which revolves around asynchronous queues - e.g. if the destination server is offline when the client sends a message, the message will be queued on the client until the server comes back online. Each queue is one way only, although bidirectional communication can be achieved via a second queue back from server to client. Sending WCF MSMQ messages requires that the `MSMQ` Service be installed on the client. Messages on the queue can have a delivery 'timeout' else will be placed on an applicable dead letter queue.

Real world examples:

- I would use `NetTcpBinding` with binary serialization for high performance, synchronous communication needs between a Microsoft WCF client and server, e.g. uploading files, media etc where `Xml` would not be useful (otherwise, I would use `wsHttpBinding` for synchronous `Xml` / `SOAP` messaging)
- I would use `MSMQBinding` with DTC enabled to ensure reliable messaging between 2 or more systems (e.g. financial), with at least one of the endpoints being in .Net, and a 'compatable' server (not necessarily `WCF`, e.g. `BizTalk`, or other `EAI` hubs or `ESB` buses which have adapters for `MSMQ`, e.g. Bridges exist between `MSMQ and MQSeries`). Messages would typically be in an `Xml` format.

**TL;DR**

> Does that mean the even if service is not running still client using the service

Yes. If `MSMQ` is running locally, the client will get an immediate return <del>successful response</del> (indicating that the message has been queued). This does not however mean that the message has been successfully received by the server.

Comment: Great answer, I've used extensively used WCF in a number of complex systems and just wanted to add my two cents. 1. Avoid defaulting to WCF except for very specific use cases where it provides something that lacks in RESTful webservices; 9/10 times the headache of WCF just isnt worth the reward. 2. NetTcpBinding is arguably the best (and definitely the fastest - excluding named pipes) binding option in my personal experience. It does not however have any built in redundancy as the poster explains.

Comment: Agree - its been 4 years and xml is now mostly repaced by JSON services, and WebApi has now surplanted WCF in a RESTful world.