# How to configure message format for a binding in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, architecture

I found that there are default messaging formats for existing binding types. However, if I need to choose a XML message format in TCP binding, would that be configured in `app.config` itself?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose WCF supports different message format transports, but however, one should choose a binding corresponding to the message encoding type that is intended to be transported.

On Referring [this SO ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760839/does-wcf-always-use-soap-to-send-information-over-your-binding), custom web message formats are supported by WebHttpBinding (GET Json etc) and [this SO ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349690/wcf-netmsmqbinding-vs-nettcpbinding) refers `nettcpbinding` to support binary encoded format of XML.

I don't think the message types could be configured in app.config, for eg, a Json type could not be chosen for NetTCPbinding over the config file